# Serving a static file with a dynamic name?

Tags: node.js, dynamic, server

**Is this possible with node.js?**

A http server that serves files for a directory, but the files don't exist

http://example.com/sever/xyz.php

http://example.com/sever/nemlss.php

http://example.com/sever/whatever.php

...any file request - I wan't to serve a document 'hello world'

Please don't ask why!

**Just node.js**

Comment: What do you mean by "serves files for a directory"? How one can serve a file for a directory?

Comment: a http request serves a file I am asking if I can serve html by calling it any name

Comment: is this of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933510/node-js-server-404-not-found-message-to-404-html-page