# I have made a Image Slider but want to add text to it each slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning javascript.  I have made a image slider but want to add text to each slide I have 5 images just want to add the text to each slide and it be in the middle and centre from top to bottom. Thanks guys

```js
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var time = 3250;

// Image List
images[0] = 'http://lorempixel.com/300/200';
images[1] = 'http://placehold.it/300x200';
images[2] = 'http://lorempixel.com/300/200';
images[3] = 'http://placehold.it/300x200';
images[4] = 'http://lorempixel.com/300/200';

// Change Image
function changeImg(){
  document.slide.src = images[i];

  if (i < images.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }

  setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}

window.onload = changeImg;
```

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}

#wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>JS Slider </h1>
<div id="wrapper">
  <img name="slide" alt="slide image">
</div>
```

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933510/node-js-server-404-not-found-message-to-404-html-page

Answer (score 0):

In order to display unique text per picture, you first have to implement an object that holds these two values:

```
var images = [];

function appendImage(src, text) {
    images.push({
        src: src,
        text: text
    });
}
```

Then create your 5 images like so:

```
appendImage('1.jpg', 'Picture 1');
appendImage('2.jpg', 'Picture 2');
appendImage('3.jpg', 'Picture 3');
appendImage('4.jpg', 'Picture 4');
appendImage('5.jpg', 'Picture 5');
```

Just make sure you have an element that's propely placed (using CSS) to fill with text

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img name="slide" alt="slide image">
    <span id="sliderText"></span>
</div>
```

The change to your `changeImg` function will be minor, you just need to consider the new data structure.

```
var sliderText = document.getElementById('sliderText');
function changeImg(){
    document.slide.src = images[i].src;
    sliderText.innerHTML = images[i].text;
    if (i < images.length - 1) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }
    setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript objects:

```js
var i = 0;

var images = [];

var time = 3250;

// Image List

images[0] = {
  url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/120x120',
  caption: '120x120'
};
images[1] = {
  url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/130x130',
  caption: '130x130'
};
images[2] = {
  url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/140x140',
  caption: '140x140'
};
images[3] = {
  url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/150x150',
  caption: '150x150'
};
images[4] = {
  url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/160x160',
  caption: '160x160'
};


// Change Image

function changeImg() {

  document.slide.src = images[i].url;
  caption.innerText = images[i].caption;

  if (i < images.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }

  setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}

window.onload = changeImg;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>JS Slider </h1>
<div id="wrapper">
  <img name="slide" alt="slide image">
  <div id="caption">2134234</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5Lr8sdg/1/)

Comment: JS 101. Don't eval strings in setTimeouts / setIntervals. Use their function names instead.

Comment: Also can you come up with anything more sleek than `images[0] = {` ?